# Haversine and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, haversine

I'm attempting to compare a users location (Sent via params in the URL) to offers.offer_lat and offers.offer_long (in my DB) by a distance argument (set in miles)

I'm going crazy right now, a lot of solutions I have found online are proving hard to port over to laravels query builder using DB::raw, I currently have the function in a query scope as the user will be filtering API results using distance, no luck though!

I found some functions online for calculating the haversine but I have no idea how to use them. Here's an example:
https://gist.github.com/fhferreira/9081607

Any help would be massively appreciated! :)

Thanks

Comment: You have the solution right under your fingers, put the function found in your own link into a controller and use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you don't need all the bloat that is in that gist, instead, you can use the following formulae:

```
public function get_offers_near($latitude, $longitude, $radius = 1){

    $offers = Offer::select('offers.*')
        ->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                           cos( radians( offer_lat ) )
                           * cos( radians( offer_long ) - radians(?)
                           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                           sin( radians( offer_lat ) ) )
                         ) AS distance', [$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
        ->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$radius])
        ->get();

    return $offers;
}
```

This assumes that you pass in the `latitude` and `longitude` from your user. Also, if you don't want the radius to be 1, you can pass in the 3rd argument and provide a custom radius.

And of course, we're assuming that this is for a model of `Offer`. Change your naming convention where required.

Comment: For any finding this.  In the event you get non grouping field error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053335/laravel-5-3-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1463-non-grouping-field-distance

Answer (score 3):

Haversine in Laravel works in this way:

```
                Travel::select(
                    DB::raw("travels.*,
                          ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) *
                            cos( radians( lat ) )
                            * cos( radians( lon ) - radians($lng)
                            ) + sin( radians($lat) ) *
                            sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
                ->orderBy('distance', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

and you will get a collection of points ordered by distance (nearest first)

Was used travel model with params *lat* and *lng*. parameter *distance* is added by the raw query