# Laravel 5.3: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'distance' is used in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

This error came up after moving the whole source to the 5.3 version, and I'm scratching my head for over two hours now.

So I have this kind of eloquent query:

```
POI::select('*', DB::raw("SQRT( POW((x - {$this->x}),2) + POW((y - {$this->y}),2) ) AS distance"))
        ->where('status', Config::get('app.poi_state.enabled'))
        ->whereNotIn('id', $excludePOIList)
        ->having('distance', '<=', $distance)
        ->orderBy('distance')->get();
```

It worked find before upgrade now it throws:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'distance'
>   is used in HAVING clause (SQL: select *, SQRT( POW((x - 860.0000),2) + POW((y - 105.0000),2) ) AS distance from `poi` where `status` = 1 and `id` not in (1) having `distance` <= 6 order by `distance` asc)

I wanted to check if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode is enabled on my server, but it isn't...

> SELECT @@sql_mode 
>   NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

The same query works fine in MySQL workbench. 
What's going on?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Check in the config/database.php file in the mysql conection that the strict is false:

```
'strict' => false,
```

If is true, put in false.

Comment: That was it, apparently the strict mode is enabled by default in L 5.3

Comment: Thanks, but any explanation about what this `strict` option does and what side effects it has?

Comment: Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.) Strict mode also affects DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: Super weird but our servers use MySQL 5.6 while my local environment uses 5.7. Using strict locally on 5.7 works but fails in production on 5.6. My guess for the switch from `false` to `true` in L5.3 is that MySQL 5.7 came with an update that maybe fixed a bug in strict mode or something...in any case this solution worked for me. Time to upgrade our MySQL version!

Comment: This shouldn't be the right answer, disabling strict mode is NOT the solution, only avoiding the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your database.php file. Just go to **config/database.php**. Make

`'strict' => false` .

if it is "true". Then you **must** need to clear configuration. To do this just run

`php artisan optimize:clear`.

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

Try using group by clause on distance field.

```
  POI::select('*', DB::raw("SQRT( POW((x - {$this->x}),2) + POW((y - {$this->y}),2) ) AS distance"))
    ->where('status', Config::get('app.poi_state.enabled'))
    ->whereNotIn('id', $excludePOIList)
    ->groupBy('distance')
    ->having('distance', '<=', $distance)
    ->orderBy('distance')->get();
```

Comment: It won't work because the same strict rule (only_full_group_by) applies to the above query. In this case you must either include all selected columns in your groupBy statement or only select the "distance" column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get that error after the upgrade but not before. However you can move the distance condition into WHERE clause:

```
->where(DB::raw("SQRT( POW((x - {$this->x}),2) + POW((y - {$this->y}),2) ) "), '<=', $distance)
```