# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Search' not Found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel we are trying to add (https://github.com/TomLingham/Laravel-Searchy) to our project (https://github.com/wvulibraries/rockefeller-css/tree/trying-searchy) to allow the search of multiple fields in a table. I can see the package is in the vendor folder as tom-lingham for some reason I am not able to even use it. I get FatalThrowableError in DataViewController.php line 79: Class 'App\http\Controllers\Search' not Found. I followed the instructions in the github repo. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
// Import the table and collection models
use App\Table;
use App\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
/**
* The controller is responsible for showing the cards data
*/
class DataViewController extends Controller {
/**
* Constructor that associates the middlewares
*
* @return void
*/
public function __construct(){
// Middleware to check for authenticated
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
/**
* Show the data from the selected table
*/
public function index(Request $request, $curTable){
// Get the table entry in meta table "tables"
$curTable = Table::find($curTable);
if(!$curTable->hasAccess){
  return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors(['Table is disabled']);
}
// Get and return of table doesn't have any records
$numOfRcrds = DB::table($curTable->tblNme)->count();
// check for the number of records
if ($numOfRcrds == 0){
  return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors(['Table does not have any records.']);
}
// Get the records 30 at a time
$rcrds = DB::table($curTable->tblNme)->paginate(30);
// retrieve the column names
$clmnNmes = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($curTable->tblNme);
// return the index page
return view('user.data')->with('rcrds',$rcrds)
                        ->with('clmnNmes',$clmnNmes)
                        ->with('tblNme',$curTable->tblNme)
                        ->with('tblId',$curTable);
}
public function show(Request $request, $curTable, $curId){
// Get the table entry in meta table "tables"
$curTable = Table::find($curTable);
if(!$curTable->hasAccess){
  return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors(['Table is disabled']);
}
// Check if search string and column were passed
if (strlen($curId) != 0) {
  $numOfRcrds = DB::table($curTable->tblNme)
                  ->where('id', '=', $curId)
                  ->count();
  // check for the number of records
  if ($numOfRcrds == 0){
    return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors(['Search Yeilded No Results']);
  }
  else {
    // $rcrds = DB::table($curTable->tblNme)
    //             ->where('id', '=', $curId)
    //             ->get();
    $rcrds = Searchy::search($curTable->tblNme)->fields('id')->query($curId)->get();
  }
}
else {
  return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors(['Invalid ID']);
}
// retrieve the column names
$clmnNmes = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($curTable->tblNme);
// return the index page
return view('user.show')->with('rcrds',$rcrds)
                        ->with('clmnNmes',$clmnNmes)
                        ->with('tblNme',$curTable->tblNme)
                        ->with('tblId',$curTable);
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: Might be a namespacing issue; include `Search` as a `use ...\Search as Search` in your controller, or use absolute path in your code, such as `$search = new \Search();`. Also, showing the full `DataViewController` code would be quite helpful.

Comment: RousseauAlexandre - yes I tried composer install and still got the error.

Comment: The controller can be viewed here https://github.com/wvulibraries/rockefeller-css/blob/trying-searchy/src/project-css/app/Http/Controllers/DataViewController.php I also added it to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into a namespacing issue.

Your controller is in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, so that's where it will look by default. At the top of your controller, adding a `use Searchy;` line alongside the existing `use` lines will make it work, **or** you can preface `Searchy` with a `\` to tell PHP to start at the namespace root.

```
$rcrds = \Searchy::search(...);
```

Comment: Side note: You'll run into this all over Laravel (or any modern PHP framework), so read up on PHP's docs on namespaces and understand how it's all working.

Comment: Thanks did work but now I get a different error. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'relevance' is used

Comment: @TracyMcCormick Googling that error shows a variety of answers here on SO. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053335/laravel-5-3-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1463-non-grouping-field-distance

Comment: thanks I found the same post and it did fix it thanks again.