# how can i find the near places by long and lat by laravel

Tags: laravel

my database :

```
|----|------|------|
| id | lat  | long |
|----|------|------|
```

when i used this code:

```
public function near($lat ,$lng)
{

    $cities = map::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6367 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
                ->where('distance', '<', 25)
                ->orderBy('distance')
                ->get();
    return response($cities);
}
```

it give me error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long ) - radians(5) ) + sin( radians(28) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distan' at line 1 (SQL: select *, ( 6367 * acos( cos( radians(28) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians(5) ) + sin( radians(28) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance from `maps` where `distance` < 25 order by `distance` asc)

Comment: show your model map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haversine and Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467774/haversine-and-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias to get distance

```
$dist = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians($location->latitude)) 
                     * cos(radians(model.latitude)) 
                     * cos(radians(model.longitude) 
                     - radians($location->longitude)) 
                     + sin(radians($location->latitude)) 
                     * sin(radians(model.latitude))))";
     return $query
        ->select() //pick the columns you want here.
        ->selectRaw("{$dist} AS distance")
        ->whereRaw("{$dist} < 25");
```

Comment: it return to me the same distance 
like :[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "long": "-108.6595174215",
    "lat": "54.1725240238",
    "user_id": 37,
    "distance": 5078.346610130264
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "long": "37.5555555555",
    "lat": "28.2448236452",
    "user_id": 181,
    "distance": 5078.346610130264
  }
]